# Google Assistance Web URL request and get speaker reply IFTTT?

Tags: httprequest, webhooks, google-assistant, ifttt

I would like to use my google assistance to manage my home automation.
The objective is to communicate with my local system via Google assistance, URL-API to my home automation and IFTTT

I know how to use Google Assistant in IFFTT, to send URL request but I'm not able to get the reply 'text' and let Google assistant to reply with voice.
Here the step I would like to do :

1. Hey Google, House what is the temperature in the bedroom ?
2. the text "what is the temperature in the bedroom ?" is sent to my home automation via URL (API URL)
3. My Home automation replies by texte written
4. IFTTT get the reply written and request to Google Assistant to speak the texte received
   Of course IFTTT has to speak to the requester (the device requested the action)

Today I know to run the step 1 and step 2

1 - IFTTT - If this

- List item
- 'Google Assistant' - Say a phrase with a text ingredient

2 - IFTTT - Then

- Make a web request
- [https://myhouse.com/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=xxx&type=interact&query={{TextField}}&utf8=1](https://myhouse.com/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=xxx&type=interact&query=%7B%7BTextField%7D%7D&utf8=1)

3 - my Home Automation return the info (If I copy past to my chrome the URL generated by IFTTT) I got the answer, but I'm not able to continue and how to get the value in IFTTT
???

4 - How to do it ???

With an Exemple

1. Hey Google, House What is the temperature in the bedroom
2. [https://myhouse.com/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=xxx&type=interact&query={{what](https://myhouse.com/core/api/jeeApi.php?apikey=xxx&type=interact&query=%7B%7Bwhat) is the temperature in the bedroom}}&utf8=1
3. If I copy the URL generated by IFTTT (get from interaction Activity) and copy to my chrome, My home automation provide the answer : Temp Bedroom, Temperature 18.5 °C

Thanks in advance for your support on it